# Why I cannot put the received (by the alamofire call) token in the keychain in my swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, keychain

I have a webservice that returns me some data like `name`, `login` and `auth_token`. So far I was saving `name` and `login` in the NSUserDefaults. Now I want to store safely also `auth_token`, so I've decided to put it in the keychain. For that purpose I've decided to use https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith this plugin.

So far my code looked like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(serverURL)/authorization", parameters: params)
    .validate()
    .response { (request, response, data, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print("error = \(error)") 
        }else{

            let username = json["name"]
            let login = json["login"]
            let auth_token = json["auth_token"]

            let defaults =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            defaults.setObject(login, forKey: "login")
            defaults.setObject(username, forKey: "username")

            defaults.synchronize() 

            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabController") as? TabController {
                self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
            }

        }
}
```

but when I added this line:

```
 try Locksmith.saveData(["auth_token": json["auth_token"]], forUserAccount: "my_auth_token")
```

right after this:

```
 let defaults =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

then I'm getting error on `Alamofire.request` saying:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?'
```

So my question is - how can I save my `auth_token` that comes from the webservice in the keychain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're running into is a type mismatch, and the unfortunate fact that the AlamoFire `Request` class has both a function called `response`, and a property called `response` (of type `NSHTTPURLResponse?`, look familiar =))

In your code you're calling `try`, which requires the enclosing closure/function to be marked `throws`, or you have to wrap your code in a `do-catch`

So what the swift compiler is doing is inferring that the closure you are writing has `throws` as part of its definition. This obviously doesn't match the definition of the closure that should be passed to the `func response`, so it tries the *other* `response` it can find, the property. Then it just completely fails because you cannot try to 'call' an optional type.

You should add a do-catch inside your closure to handle the possible errors that Locksmith may throw.

Edit: In response to your comment. You just need to wrap that call in a do catch to properly handle errors. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html for details on Swifts error handling model.

As for which error to catch, just glancing through the Locksmith API, it can throw errors that it receives from the Keychain API. Luckily they have defined the errors they throw here: https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith/blob/master/Source/LocksmithError.swift

As an example of what to write, it would just be something like this

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(serverURL)/authorization", parameters: params)
    .validate()
    .response { (request, response, data, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print("error = \(error)") 
        }else{

            let username = json["name"]
            let login = json["login"]
            let auth_token = json["auth_token"]

            let defaults =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            do {
                try Locksmith.saveData(["auth_token": json["auth_token"]], forUserAccount: "my_auth_token")
            } catch {
                // Handle the error, however you best see fit
                print("Error trying to save to keychain \(error)")
            }

            defaults.setObject(login, forKey: "login")
            defaults.setObject(username, forKey: "username")

            defaults.synchronize() 

            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabController") as? TabController {
                self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Hm, thank you for a very clear answer! Two questions though - 1) could you show me a small code snippet of how and where exactly could I put it? and the 2nd thing - you wrote about errors that Locksmith may throw - I just thought it's a normal way of storing data in a keystore - what can go wrong here? :D

Comment: @user3766930 If my updated answer helped you, please accept it as an answer